# How to read vm file into web content folder of tomcat server

Tags: file, spring-mvc

I want to read the vm file into web content folder of tomcat server. But not able to do this.

I am using tomcat server with eclipse.

Dir stucture looks like this

(source code structure)
src 
   com
      controller
               ReportController

(Web content structure)

webcontent
          resources
                   test.vm

My code like looks

```
ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();
String path = context.getContextPath() + "resources/test.vm";
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(path); 

ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
//renderer.setDocumentFromString( HTML_STRING);  //for well formatted HTML String
renderer.setDocument(url);
renderer.layout();
renderer.createPDF(os);        
os.close();
```

can some one help me on this topic......

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: it shows resource not found exception.

Comment: Is your resources directory under WEB-INF?  Because `getContextPath()` is the path to the Servlet context, which is more of the URL that for direct file access.

Comment: I found the other solution. basically i am using velocity template to generate html. and did not config the velocity engine properly. But now i have done this. and now working properly. Any way thanks to support.

Comment: Might I suggest you add the solution, or at least a link to it, as an answer to the question?  This way people who have similar problems in the future will have some help other that "I misconfigured it..."

Comment: @StillLearning any update on this. I'm facing the same issue.